# How to access values from List<MyObject> something; created with thymleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Im trying to access the data from the controller stored like this but i dont know how:

```
   *{regDatas[__1__].firstname}
```

I have a Wrapper class

```
 public class RegDatas {
        private List<RegData> regDatas;

        public List<RegData> getRegDatas() {
            return regDatas;
        }

        public void setRegDatas(List<RegData> regDatas) {
            this.regDatas =regDatas;
        }
    }
```

My class to store values

```
public class RegData {
    private String firstname;

    public String getFirstname() {
          return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
          this.firstname = firstname;
    }
}
```

I stored some values with thymeleaf from input fields like this

```
<input required="required" th:class="${'checkboxDisabled2'}" type="text"  th:field="*{regDatas[__1__].firstname}"/>
<input required="required" th:class="${'checkboxDisabled1'}" type="text"  th:field="*{regDatas[__0__].firstname}"/>
```

and my Controller

```
 public String meinestammdaten(@ModelAttribute RegDatas regDatas, Model model) {

//access values sotres in regDatas.. how?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `model.addAttribute(name, value)` and access in html using tymeleaf like below code in your controller

```
public String meinestammdaten(@ModelAttribute RegDatas regDatas, Model model) {

model.addAttribute("firstName", regDatas.getFirstname());
return "html file"
}
```

Please change **html file** to according your file name

And in your thymeleaf

```
<input required="required" th:class="${'checkboxDisabled2'}" type="text"  th:field="${firstName}"/>
```

If you have the list and adding that list in the `model.addAttribute()` of regDatas then you can use `th:each="regdata : ${regdata}"`

For more info about thymeleafe visit the link http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html